# React Native - Colored fonts are black (android only)

Tags: react-native, fonts, expo

i have created custom fonts ".ttf" and ".otf" with multicolor fonts like "red", "blue" in single symbol, is there any way to display it on ANDROID ? or maybe need specific format for android ? or some special setting?, thanks

Android

- fonts are just black...

iOS

- works perfect, default is colored ( how i made it )

Expo SDK 44

for now we have to use this (maybe its bad but only solution maybe?):

- custom fonts with 4+ text symbols with color to achive this on android ...

```
<View>
 <Text style={[styles.textStyle, {color: '#B5B5B5'}]}></Text>
 <Text style={[styles.textStyle, {color: '#E8E8E8'}]}></Text>
 <Text style={[styles.textStyle, {color: '#B5B5B5'}]}></Text>
 <Text style={[styles.textStyle, {color: '#E8E8E8'}]}></Text>
 <Text style={[styles.textStyle, {color: '#B5B5B5'}]}></Text>
</View>
```

Comment: are you creating ttf using icomoon?

Comment: no i m using "FontCreator 12.0", with my own SVG from Adobe Illustrator

Comment: Do you show a [mcve] for this? Because with just these details, the best folks can do is guess, which SO posts shouldn't need. If you use fontcreator, generate the font with just a single glyph so that it's small enough to just inline as a base64 encoded data uri in your CSS (`@font-face { font-family: ...; src: url(data:....); }` rather than having to upload a font somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

This was my solution when I faced a *slightly* similar issue with fonts some months back:

Tip: Use **processFontFamily** from expo-fonts library (comes with Expo workflows)

<Text fontFamily={processFontFamily("Lato-Bold")}> opening tag.

Comment: tried, but nothing